# Задача с Codewars. Return отдает undefined

Tags: javascript

---

Задача с кодварс.
Есть функция, которая принимает строку, превращает в массив чисел, определяет четных ли чисел больше или нечетных и возвращает порядковый номер числа, которое отличается четностью от остальных чисел в массиве.
Снизу для проверки блок с консоль.логами, через пробел указал верное значение, который ожидается от функции. Собственно, задача решена, но return nums.indexOf(e) возвращает undefined, хотя строчкой выше console.log(nums.indexOf(e) прекрасно возвращает нужный индекс. Вопрос в том, почему функция возвращает undefined?

```
function iqTest(numbers) {
  let nums = numbers.split(" ");
  let even = [];
  let odd = [];
  let count = false;

  nums.forEach((element) => {
    if (element % 2 == 0) {
      even.push(element);
    } else {
      odd.push(element);
    }
    if (odd.length > even.length) {
      count = false;
    } else {
      count = true;
    }
  });

  nums.forEach((e) => {
    if (count == true) {
      if (e % 2 != 0) {
        console.log(nums.indexOf(e) + 1);
        return nums.indexOf(e) + 1;
      }
    } else {
      if (e % 2 == 0) {
        console.log(nums.indexOf(e) + 1);
        return nums.indexOf(e) + 1;
      }
    }
  });
}

console.log(iqTest("2 4 7 8 10") + "   3");
console.log(iqTest("1 2 2") + "   1");
console.log(
  iqTest("88 96 66 51 14 88 2 92 18 72 18 88 20 30 4 82 90 100 24 46") + "   4"
);
console.log(iqTest("100 99 100") + "   2");
console.log(iqTest("5 3 2") + "   3");
console.log(iqTest("43 28 1 91") + "   2");
console.log(
  iqTest(
    "20 94 56 50 10 98 52 32 14 22 24 60 4 8 98 46 34 68 82 82 98 90 50 20 78 49 52 94 64 36"
  ) + "   26"
);
console.log(
  iqTest(
    "79 27 77 57 37 45 27 49 65 33 57 21 71 19 75 85 65 61 23 97 85 9 23 1 9 3 99 77 77 21 79 69 15 37 15 7 93 81 13 89 91 31 45 93 15 97 55 80 85 83"
  ) + "   48"
);
console.log(iqTest("100 100 1") + "   3");
console.log(
  iqTest(
    "9 31 27 93 17 77 75 9 9 53 89 39 51 99 5 1 11 39 27 49 91 17 27 79 81 71 37 75 35 13 93 4 99 55 85 11 23 57 5 43 5 61 15 35 23 91 3 81 99 85 43 37 39 27 5 67 7 33 75 59 13 71 51 27 15 93 51 63 91 53 43 99 25 47 17 71 81 15 53 31 59 83 41 23 73 25 91 9"
  ) + "   32"
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде `return` возвращает значение не из `iqTest()`, а из функции-колбека в `forEach()`, и возвращает в никуда, потому что значение колбеков в   `forEach()` никак не обрабатываются.

Вы немного переусложнили решение, попробуйте так:

```js
function iqTest(numbers) {
  let nums = numbers.split(" ");
  let even = [];
  let odd = [];

  nums.forEach((element) => {
    if (element % 2 == 0) {
      even.push(element);
    } else {
      odd.push(element);
    }
  });

  if (odd.length > even.length) {
    return nums.indexOf(even[0]) + 1;
  } else {
    return nums.indexOf(odd[0]) + 1;
  }
}

console.log(iqTest("2 4 7 8 10") + "   3");
console.log(iqTest("1 2 2") + "   1");
console.log(
  iqTest("88 96 66 51 14 88 2 92 18 72 18 88 20 30 4 82 90 100 24 46") + "   4"
);
console.log(iqTest("100 99 100") + "   2");
console.log(iqTest("5 3 2") + "   3");
console.log(iqTest("43 28 1 91") + "   2");
console.log(
  iqTest(
    "20 94 56 50 10 98 52 32 14 22 24 60 4 8 98 46 34 68 82 82 98 90 50 20 78 49 52 94 64 36"
  ) + "   26"
);
console.log(
  iqTest(
    "79 27 77 57 37 45 27 49 65 33 57 21 71 19 75 85 65 61 23 97 85 9 23 1 9 3 99 77 77 21 79 69 15 37 15 7 93 81 13 89 91 31 45 93 15 97 55 80 85 83"
  ) + "   48"
);
console.log(iqTest("100 100 1") + "   3");
console.log(
  iqTest(
    "9 31 27 93 17 77 75 9 9 53 89 39 51 99 5 1 11 39 27 49 91 17 27 79 81 71 37 75 35 13 93 4 99 55 85 11 23 57 5 43 5 61 15 35 23 91 3 81 99 85 43 37 39 27 5 67 7 33 75 59 13 71 51 27 15 93 51 63 91 53 43 99 25 47 17 71 81 15 53 31 59 83 41 23 73 25 91 9"
  ) + "   32"
);
```

Comment: Действительно. Теперь все понятно, спасибо.